# How to use webworker in angular2 for processing jQuery/Bootstrap datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, angular, web-worker

I'm using jQuery Datatable for rendering table of angular 2 view, but because of too Big size of data, my table freezes and so the browser.

So is there any way that I can run Datatable in Webworker, If there is How to do it in angular 2.

Or some other way to improve performance of Datatable so the browser and Datatable doesn't freeze. 
I'm painting 20 thousands or more records with 20 columns.

My code for painting Datatable is following:

```
this.dtaTable =jQuery('#dataTbl').DataTable({
            iDisplayLength: 8,
            bLengthChange : false,
            buttons: [{
              extend: 'copy',
              exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
              }
            },{
              extend: 'excel',
              exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
              }
            },{
              extend: 'pdf',
              exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
              }
            },{
              extend: 'print',
              exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
              }
            },
              'colvis'],
          });
```